# Complex analysis to determine whether a function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please help me solve this question i have tried using the cauchy riemann equations but they have not  yielded favourable results
The question is as follows :-
Suppose if f(x+iy) =u(x,y) +iv(x,y) is C differentiable on a domain S in C .Suppose v(x,y)=exp(u(x,y)) Show that f(x,y) is constant.

Answer (score 0):

So your function is $f(x+iy)=u(x,y) + ie^{u(x,y)}$ which is holomorphic on $S$.  So for all $z=x+iy$ in $S$, Cauchy Riemann equations hold:
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} e^{u(x,y)}  $$
and
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^{u(x,y)} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} e^{-u(x,y)} $$
Subtracting second equation from the first, 
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} (e^{u(x,y)}+e^{-u(x,y)})=0, \quad x+iy \in S$$
which means $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ on $S$. A similar argument can show $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ on $S$.  From which we have $u$ is constant, hence $v4 is constant